# Click on specific Button (Selenium Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

here I have 2 buttons:

Clicked Button:

```
<button type="button" data-testid="favorite-button" class="styles__button--1wSNn styles__neutral--17MuV styles__elevation--2fhDh styles__elevationMedium--2eus4 styles__circle--3zgIv styles__small--127Kw"><span class="styles__iconAfter--3xNI0"><div class="FavoriteIcon__icon--2fuH8 FavoriteIcon__small--2hXns FavoriteIcon__favorited--zicAG"><img class="styles__image--2CwxX" src="/boom/client/f0605f03fa478593f75f791e8eea8889.svg" data-testid="heartFilled" alt="Favorited"></div></span></button>
```

Unclicked Button:

```
<button type="button" data-testid="favorite-button" class="styles__button--1wSNn styles__neutral--17MuV styles__elevation--2fhDh styles__elevationMedium--2eus4 styles__circle--3zgIv styles__small--127Kw"><span class="styles__iconAfter--3xNI0"><div class="FavoriteIcon__icon--2fuH8 FavoriteIcon__small--2hXns"><img class="styles__image--2CwxX" src="/boom/client/fe5b59d42e7d54796992f8f9914d3e45.svg" data-testid="heartOutline" alt="Favorite"></div></span></button>
```

How can I make it click only on the unclicked buttons?

I've already tried that:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type="image"][@src="/boom/client/fe5b59d42e7d54796992f8f9914d3e45.svg"]).click()`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using css selector. ```driver.find_element_by_css_selector([src="/boom/client/fe5b59d42e7d54796992f8f9914d3e45.svg"]).click()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Click `unclicked` button Use the below `Xpath` to click.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.//img[data-testid='heartOutline']]").click()
```

---

To avoid synronization Issue Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.//img[data-testid='heartOutline']]"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```